# how add facet to a seaborn jointplot with seaborn and save it in a PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe, `dt`, that looks like this:

```
      g      t           n
0     A    0.0    2.468644
1     A    1.0    6.473590
2     A    2.0    9.445034
3     A    3.0   12.381784
4     A    4.0   14.570846
..   ..    ...         ...
133  no   26.0   67.000000
134  no   27.0   38.000000
135  no   28.0   61.000000
136  no   36.0   58.000000
137  no  107.0  132.000000
```

I can plot a `jointplot` using seaborn as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.jointplot('n', 't', dt, kind='kde')
```

I would like to add to this plot a `facetwrap` on column `g` and also add this plot in the `pdf`

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
PdfPages('joinplot.pdf')
```

Is there a way to do that ?